# SMD chip identification - top marking "LA" then sideways "4"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image]

Does anybody know this chip? It gets input from a photo-resistor and triggers a solar light circuit.

Comment: i just have to give you an upvote for the photography

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! Very nice of you !!! I used a Digital microscope camera !!!

Answer (score 1):

Original Part no. NL17SZ14

Datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nl17sz14-d.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).